# Google Map Api with key not working

Tags: php, api, google-maps

Iam using google map for showing different peoples in different location. I already purchased Google Maps API key for Work customers. I added my key to the search like below.

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$_SESSION['userlat'].",".$_SESSION['userllong']."&sensor=false&key=XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXX";
$details=file_get_contents($url);       
$geocodedinfo = json_decode($details,true);
```

But sometimes i get a message OVER_QUERY_LIMIT and maps shows empty. But i won't use 100,000 requests per 24 hour period., 10 requests per second

**AM I USING THE RIGHT FORMAT FOR ADDING API KEY**

Now iam getting map like below. None of my users are not listing there. But sometimes its works fine.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the `$_SESSION` contains the right values as expected? Have you checked the generated source?

Comment: **GENERATED STATUS CODE: REQUEST_DENIED**

Answer (score 1):

**OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** seems like you are sending request `file_get_contents($url)` in a loop, Before 1 week i tackle with this issue by using Caching. But i didn't used KEY to fetch the `latlng`.

As you said **But sometimes its works fine**. Store the LatLng value in Cache and Apply on map by cached DATA.

I Used cacheing in WordPress, so its is also easy to update any latlng to me in wordpress.

If you are not familiar with cacheing then store it in a text file **[In Well format so that its easy to fetch or compare]**.